# MySQL regexp much slow than like

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

```
SELECT data 
  FROM test 
 WHERE col REGEXP "asdf_[0-9]+" 
 LIMIT 1
```

...1 row in set (1 min 43.12 sec)

```
SELECT data 
  FROM test 
 WHERE col LIKE "asdf_%" 
 LIMIT 1
```

...1 row in set (0.01 sec)

`regexp` can give me the exact result, I have to filter data if I use `like` sql.  Is there some way to improve?

BTW: test has 2 million rows and grow up.

Comment: REGEXP will always be equivalent to using `LIKE '%asdf_%'`.  Use Full Text Search to get better performance.

Comment: Clarification - are you wanting all `col` that start with `asdf_[0-9]+`, or do you want the *entire* `col` to match the pattern `asdf_[0-9]+`?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your `regexp` string to `"^asdf_[0-9]+"`.

`LIKE` is anchored (ie `LIKE 'asdf_%'` says "a string starting with asdf_"), whereas `REGEXP` is not (`REGEXP 'asdf_[0-9]+'` looks for that anywhere within the string).

Note that doing `REGEXP 'asdf_[0-9]+'` is like saying `LIKE '%asdf_%'`.

I think `REGEXP` will still be a bit slower than `LIKE`, but hopefully the start of line anchor will greatly speed it up.

Comment: Slower... `1 row in set (1 min 52.61 sec)`

Comment: That's odd, I've never experienced the addition of a `^` *slowing* down a regex - sorry, can't help you then (try the full text search like @OMGPonies suggested, but I don't know enough about that to help you).

Comment: Ok, re your clarification, try `^asdf_[0-9]+$` as your `regexp` and see if that speeds it up.

Comment: You may also need to give more context - I just made a table filled with 2million text strings (albeit not very long), and both `LIKE 'asdf_%'` and `REGEXP '^asdf_[0-9]+'` (in combination with `LIMIT 1`) gave 0.01 sec. What sort of strings are in there (ie how long are they?)? what's the column type? etc.